# finding the path of a point of a square in which two of its other points are translated along perpendicular lines

Tags: geometry

> Given a square $ABCD$ where $A=(0,0)$, $B=(0,12)$, $C=(12,12)$ and $D=(12,0)$.  I want to find the equation for the path point $C$ travels on if point A  > B via AB and B > C via BC

Solidworks got me the results I wanted but I would still like to know the math behind these curves.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you move point $A$ up to $(0,t)$.  $B$ should now be the point on the line $y=12$ in the first quadrant at distance $12$ from $(0,t)$. Thus it is $(x,12)$ where
$(12-t)^2 + x^2 = 12^2$, so $x = \sqrt{24 t - t^2}$.  Now $B-A = (\sqrt{24t - t^2},12) - (0,t) = (\sqrt{24t - t^2}, 12-t)$.  $C-B$ is orthogonal to this and in the fourth quadrant, thus $(12-t, -\sqrt{24t - t^2})$, so $C = B + (12-t, -\sqrt{24t - t^2}) = (12-t+\sqrt{24t-t^2},12-\sqrt{24t-t^2})$.

The path of $C$ is actually part of an ellipse: $x^2 + 2 x y + 2 y^2 - 24 x - 48 y + 144 = 0$.

[image]

Comment: this is awesome thanks!